# PE File section relocation and stack cookies -> Error

Tags: windows, assembly, memory

i'm trying to increase the size of a pe section which is located after the .text section. I want to increase the size of .rdata by 0x1000 to go from this layout

[image: layout before]

to that layout

[image: layout after]

by adding 0x1000 as an offset k to the section size.

What am i doing to achieve this:

- Adding extra size/offset (k) to the "VirtualSize" property of the pe file
- Adding the offset k to all "VirtualAddress" properties of all following sections
- Adding the offset k to the "SizeOfImage" property of the pe header
- Adding k to all data directory adresses greater or equal 0x5000

What's the problem:
I can start the pe file without the windows loader complaining. Still the new exe crashes because of a call to "_security_init_cookie". If however i use a debugger to patch out the stack cookie calls and jump directly to the real main the programm start's normally.

My question:
How can i fix this error concerning the stack cookies? Where are the adresses in the pe file i need to patch to do so?

I'm aware i'd normally need to patch the reloc table too. In this case i have checked that there are no entries for the sections i want to relocate.

Comment: Maybe you also need to patch the relocations? To be sure: you don't also want to increase the size of `.rodata` in the file, do you?

Comment: The PECOFF format doesn't support moving sections relative to other sections like this. You can append a section at the end, but you can't insert or expand a section in the middle. If the executable isn't relocatable then all addresses are fixed and all sections need to be loaded at their specified addresses. If the executable is relocatable then entire executable image needs relocated as a single block, so that the distance between any two locations never changes.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm aware of this fact. I just thought that since it's after the code section and there are no relocations for the following sections it should work.

Comment: Could i iterate through the code section fixing all references? I mean effectively i don't need to fix jumps since it's after the code section. I'd need analyze the code section for mov other reference commands check their adresses and fix them.